# Python Matplotlib animation frames are overlapping

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, orbital-mechanics

I am working on my orbit program, and I have currently only animated the moon with a downward (-y) velocity of -1023. The animation works, but each frame stays on the figure when the next one comes on:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import matplotlib.animation as animation

er = 6378100*10#m             #earth radius
mr = 1737400*10#m             #moon radius
em = 5.97219*10**24#kg        #earth mass
mm = 7.34767309*10**22#kg     #moon mass
d = 384400000#m               #distance earth-moon
G = 6.67384*10**(-11)         #gravity constant
mv = -1023#m/s                #Moon velocity
nts = 10000                   #no. time steps


def circle(r, h, k, a):
    x = r*math.cos(a)+h
    y = r*math.sin(a)+k
    plt.scatter(x,y)

def simData():
    tmax = 10000*nts
    ts = 10000
    x = 0.0
    t = 0.0
    while t < tmax:
        n = 0
        for i in range(120):
            circle(mr, d, mv*t, n)
            n = n + math.pi/60
        t = t + ts
        yield x, t

def simPoints(simData):
    x, t = simData[0], simData[1]
    time_text.set_text(time_template%(t))
    line.set_data(t, x)
    return line, time_text



fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-430000000, 430000000), ylim=(-430000000, 430000000))

line, = ax.plot([], [], 'bo', ms=10)

time_template = 'Time = %.1f s'    # prints running simulation time
time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData, blit=False,\
     interval=10, repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: `matplotlib` animation does not wipe the image between frames. The point is that you yourself have to change the properties of the objects on the screen. Now you instead plot a new image with some new objects when you do the `plt.scatter` in `circle`.

I changed a few lines in your code to avoid adding new objects, see the comment lines marked with `####`. Now it should be a bit snappier. (Even though the Moon is escaping Earth's gravitational field. Pity.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import matplotlib.animation as animation

er = 6378100*10#m             #earth radius
mr = 1737400*10#m             #moon radius
em = 5.97219*10**24#kg        #earth mass
mm = 7.34767309*10**22#kg     #moon mass
d = 384400000#m               #distance earth-moon
G = 6.67384*10**(-11)         #gravity constant
mv = -1023#m/s                #Moon velocity
nts = 10000                   #no. time steps


def circle(r, h, k, a):
    x = r*math.cos(a)+h
    y = r*math.sin(a)+k
    #### CHANGED
    moony.center = x,y

def simData():
    tmax = 10000*nts
    ts = 10000
    x = 0.0
    t = 0.0
    while t < tmax:
        n = 0
        for i in range(120):
            circle(mr, d, mv*t, n)
            n = n + math.pi/60
        t = t + ts
        yield x, t

def simPoints(simData):
    x, t = simData[0], simData[1]
    time_text.set_text(time_template%(t))
    line.set_data(t, x)
    return line, time_text



fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-430000000, 430000000), ylim=(-430000000, 430000000))

#### CHANGED: a grey circle of moony dimensions to be moved around
moony = plt.Circle((0,0), mr, facecolor=(.8,.8,.8))
ax.add_artist(moony)

time_template = 'Time = %.1f s'    # prints running simulation time
time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData, blit=False,\
     interval=10, repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

Of course, you'll probably want to create a circle to illustrate Earth, as well. You do not need to have any `plt.plot` commands in the file if you just want to plot two objects.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I was planning to make a circle for the earth as well.