# Matplotlib: animation of Earth's orbit around the Sun

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I'm trying to create an animation of Earth's orbit around the Sun.

The code works great without introducing matplotlib's animation function and displays the Earth path around the Sun, but when trying to animate it the code becomes messy and ends up outputting errors, I searched for examples but found none that works for me.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Storing Coordinate Data
x_11list = []
x_12list = []

x_21list = []
x_22list = []

# Constants
G = 6.67408e-11 # m^3 kg^-1 s^-2
t = 0.0 # s
dt = 0.01*24*60*60 # s

# Sun Parameters
# mass
m_1 = 1.989e30 # kg
# position
x_11 = 0
x_12 = 0
x_13 = 0

# velocity
v_11 = 0
v_12 = 0
v_13 = 0

# Earth Parameters
# mass
m_2 = 5.972e24 # kg
# position
x_21 = 1.5e11 # m
x_22 = 0
x_23 = 0

# velocity
v_21 = 0
v_22 = 30000 # m/s
v_23 = 0

while t < 377*24*60*60:

    # Distance
    r_12 = np.sqrt((x_21-x_11)**2 + (x_22-x_12)**2 + (v_23-v_13)**2) # m

    # Newton's Second Law of Motion
    # Force 12
    Fx_11 = (G*m_1*m_2*(x_21-x_11))/r_12**3
    Fx_12 = (G*m_1*m_2*(x_22-x_12))/r_12**3
    Fx_13 = (G*m_1*m_2*(x_23-x_13))/r_12**3

    # Force 21
    Fx_21 = -(G*m_1*m_2*(x_21-x_11))/r_12**3
    Fx_22 = -(G*m_1*m_2*(x_22-x_12))/r_12**3
    Fx_23 = -(G*m_1*m_2*(x_23-x_13))/r_12**3

    # Euler Method
    # Sun
    v_11 += (Fx_11*dt)/m_1
    v_12 += (Fx_12*dt)/m_1
    v_13 += (Fx_13*dt)/m_1

    x_11 += v_11*dt
    x_12 += v_12*dt
    x_13 += v_13*dt

    # Earth
    v_21 += (Fx_21*dt)/m_2
    v_22 += (Fx_22*dt)/m_2
    v_23 += (Fx_23*dt)/m_2

    x_21 += v_21*dt
    x_22 += v_22*dt
    x_23 += v_23*dt

    t += dt

    x_11list.append(x_11)
    x_12list.append(x_12)

    x_21list.append(x_21)
    x_22list.append(x_22)

# Vizualisation
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(x_11list, x_12list, linewidth=2.0, label="Sun", color="darkorange")
plt.plot(x_21list, x_22list, linewidth=2.0, label="Earth", color="royalblue")
plt.xlabel(r"$x(m)$")
plt.ylabel(r"$y(m)$")
plt.title("Numerical Simulation of Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation")
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The output:

[image]
If possible, my expectation is to get an animation with minimal change of the original code.

Comment: Did you check e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659800/python-matplotlib-animation-frames-are-overlapping)?

Answer (score 0):

You can with [celluloid](https://github.com/jwkvam/celluloid), but one cost is computational inefficiency.

At the beginning import celluloid and construct the camera.

```
from celluloid import Camera
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
camera = Camera(fig)
plt.xlabel(r"$x(m)$")
plt.ylabel(r"$y(m)$")
plt.title("Numerical Simulation of Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation")
```

Just do scatter plots at the bottom of the for loop and "snap" pictures.

```
plt.scatter(x_11, x_12, s=300, color='darkorange')
plt.scatter(x_21, x_22, s=200, color='royalblue')
camera.snap()
```

After the for loop finishes, save the animation.

```
camera.animate().save('orbit.mp4')
```

Note, you'll probably want to increase `dt` otherwise this will take a long time. I'll leave it as an exercise to add the legends.